# How to precisely describe a dict type?

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

I am back to Python (after some infidelities with Go and Typescript) and in the meantime the `type` parameter [landed in](https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-type-statement).

I tried to understand how to use it to **precisely** describe a dict structure, but could only find a generic approach:

```py
type Car = Dict[str, str]  # or [str, Any] or whatever
```

If my dict is actually

```json
{
    "color": "blue",
    "max_nr_passengers": 26,
    "seats": [
        {
            "color": "green",
            "heated": true
        },
        {
            "color": "blue",
            "heated": true
        },
    ],
    "options": {
        "guns": false,
        "submarine": false,
        "extra_wheels": 18
    }
}
```

then I would like to be able to describe its shape so that I have true type hinting (and peace of mind).

In Go this would be something like

```golang
type Car = struct {
    Color String
    MaxNrPassengers Int
    Seats []struct {
        Color String
        Heated Bool
    }
    Options struct {
        Guns Bool
        Submarine Bool
        ExtraWheels Int
    }
}
```

and this describes accurately the actual structure of the type.

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: I'd go with classes at this point.

Comment: You could use [TypedDict](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/), but a dataclass is probably the better approach here than a dict.

Comment: Python does not have an equivalent to this yet. [Someone is developing it](https://github.com/python/typing/discussions/1391).

Comment: I would suggest using classes.

Answer (score 1):

So I would say what you're looking for is a library called `Pydantic`.

https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/

It lets you parse dict and json structures into typed classes where items are accessed as attributes. If the dict does not conform to the structure, an error is raised. See the example below:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

my_dict = {
    "color": "blue",
    "max_nr_passengers": 26,
    "seats": [
        {
            "color": "green",
            "heated": True
        },
        {
            "color": "blue",
            "heated": True
        },
    ],
    "options": {
        "guns": False,
        "submarine": False,
        "extra_wheels": 18
    }
}

class Option(BaseModel):
    guns: bool
    submarine: bool
    extra_wheels: int

class Seat(BaseModel):
    color: str
    heated: bool

class Car(BaseModel):
    color: str
    max_nr_passengers: int
    seats: list[Seat]
    options: Option

car: Car = Car.model_validate(my_dict)
print(car)
```

You can also use dataclasses for structures like this, but for nested dataclasses parsing them from dict structures is less straight forward. Hope this helps!